# How can you check if you are in a particular page in the WP Admin section? For example how can I check if I am in the Users > Your Profile page?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, api, functions

I'm building a plugin and I want to add bits of javascript in the admin head but only for certain admin pages. I don't mean pages as in a WordPress page that you create yourself but rather existing admin section pages like 'Your Profile', 'Users', etc. Is there a wp function specifically for this task? I've been looking and I can only find the boolean function `is_admin` and action hooks but not a boolean function that just checks.

Comment: Gentle nudge to remind you an answer has not been accepted. If none the answers provided answer your question sufficiently or you're struggling to understand the information provided please comment to let us know.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The way to do this is to use the 'admin_enqueue_scripts' hook to en-queue the files you need.  This hook will get passed a $hook_suffix that relates to the current page that is loaded:

```
function my_admin_enqueue($hook_suffix) {
    if($hook_suffix == 'appearance_page_theme-options') {
        wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-settings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-settings.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_style('my-theme-settings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles/theme-settings.css');
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var template_directory = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>';
        //]]>
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue');
```

Answer (score 84):

There is a global variable in wp-admin called **$pagenow** which holds name of the current page, ie edit.php, post.php, etc.

You can also check the $_GET request to narrow your location down further, for example:

```
global $pagenow;
if (( $pagenow == 'post.php' ) && ($_GET['post_type'] == 'page')) {

    // editing a page

    }

if ($pagenow == 'users.php') {

    // user listing page

    }

if ($pagenow == 'profile.php') {

    // editing user profile page

    }
```

Comment: `global $pagenow; if ( ( 'admin.php' === $pagenow ) && ( 'prefix-theme-settings' === $_GET['page'] ) ) { logic.. }` for example checks if you are on a custom theme settings page `admin.php?page=prefix-theme-settings`.

Comment: thank you . This is a great answer and helped it.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot! I tried the `$wp` global variable, but the request property would remain empty there.

Answer (score 34):

The most comprehensive method is [`get_current_screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) added in WordPress 3.1

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
```

returns

```
WP_Screen Object (
    [action] => 
    [base] => post
    [id] => post
    [is_network] => 
    [is_user] => 
    [parent_base] => edit
    [parent_file] => edit.php
    [post_type] => post
    [taxonomy] => 
)
```

Comment: "Usage Restrictions --

This function is defined on most admin pages, but not all. Thus there are cases where is_admin() will return true, but attempting to call get_current_screen() will result in a fatal error because it is not defined. One known example is wp-admin/customize.php.

The function returns null if called from the admin_init hook. It should be OK to use in a later hook such as current_screen. " -- [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen).

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy A quick check suggests this is no longer the case, as far as I can see `get_current_screen()` is safe to use on all admin pages.

Comment: @shahar this is still the case, according to the documentation linked above and my experience.

Comment: it is still the case. You can reproduce it when creating a plugin and then activating it. This will throw a fatal error on activation since you are on a page where the function is not defined :(

Comment: you can always check&bail `if (!function_exists('get_current_screen')) return ;` if your logic depends on it :)

Answer (score 11):

To offer an alternative method/approach to the above question.

```
// When you are viewing the users list or your editing another user's profile
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-users.php', 'your_enqueue_callback' );

// When you are editing your own profile
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-profile.php', 'your_enqueue_callback' );

function your_enqueue_callback() {
    wp_enqueue_script( .. YOUR ENQUEUE ARGS .. );
}
```

This method targets the specific pages more directly and avoids needing conditional logic inside your callback(because you've already made that distinction in the selected hook).

Comment: Wish i knew why this answer didn't get more votes, covers the exact use case in the question, and provides the solution in a minimal amount of code. Feedback would be nice..

Answer (score 7):

I find it weird that no one has mentioned the fact that the add_menu_page function returns an action hook which you can use to do certain actions only on those pages

```
$hook = add_menu_page($menu_title, $page_title, $capability, $slug, $function, $icon_url, $position);
add_action( 'load-' . $hook, 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(/*...*/);
    wp_enqueue_style(/*...*/);
}
```

If you need the $hook and you didn't add the menu page yourself the doc is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/)

For instance the hook for a top level menu page is

> load-toplevel_page_$MenuSlug

The hook for a submenu page is

> load-$MenuSlug_page_$SubMenuSlug

Following that logic, the hook for the user's profile page is

> load-users_page_profile