# Hiding posts and pages in panel

Tags: content, table

I found out this code and works ok for hide pages in admin page listing, but I need someway to do this to thousand pages:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts' ,'hide_pages_87ff65f5f' );

function hide_pages_87ff65f5f( $query ) {

    if( !is_admin() )
        return $query;

    global $currentpage;

  $pages = array('2389','2605','2640','2970','2626');

  if( 'edit.php' == $currentpage && ( get_query_var('post_type') && 'page' == get_query_var('post_type') ) )
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $pages );

    return $query;
}
```

Because I migrated a large static site I want to hide several pages and posts types from this specific month and year, I tried query and get_posts but something is not working, or maybe is not possible here :S

Infact I need to hide the content on every context in admin panel such parent option box, but this is quite enough for now.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't work because there is no `global $currentpage`.

There are [`$current_screen`](http://cleverwp.com/current_screen-wordpress-global-variable/) and [`$pagenow`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7281/12615).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_63414_hide_pages' );

function wpse_63414_hide_pages( $query ) {

    if( !is_admin() )
        return $query;

    global $pagenow;   
    $pages = array('2','26');

    if( 
        'edit.php' == $pagenow 
        && ( get_query_var('post_type') && 'page' == get_query_var('post_type') ) 
    )
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $pages );

    return $query;
}
```

And to hide the array of pages in the dropdown boxes these filters have to be used:

```
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'wpse_63414_hide_dropdown_pages' );
add_filter( 'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'wpse_63414_hide_dropdown_pages' );

function wpse_63414_hide_dropdown_pages( $args )
{
    $args['exclude'] = '2,26';
    return $args;
}
```

The child of the excluded pages are not shown as well. Although I'm not sure if this is the [expected behavior](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages)...

Comment: Please note:
Even if you are hidding pages with this is still possible to edit then from frontent (admin toolbar, "edit" link etc), unless you prevent this too. If you edit a child page while hidding, the parent relationship will be lost.