# Capability to read/edit page in wp-admin only for administrators

Tags: admin, wp-admin, capabilities, user-access

I want to create a page which is only for editable and readable (within wp-admin) for administrators. To restrict other users to edit any page (and not only the own ones) is not the solution as I want them to have this capability.

I am using the plugin called "Access" by wp-types.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did it go wrong? Is there code you can add to your question that may clarify what you're asking for?

Comment: I want some specific pages to be only editable and readable by administrators but no other user roles. Reason is I have some pages which only content is shortcode for a plugin or it is just a dummy page which uses a custom page template with some static content. I don't want users (except administrators) to edit or even read this page because this might be confusing for them. I tried to restrict default users to edit any page (and not only the own ones) but this can not the solution as I want them to have the capability to do so for some other reasons.

Comment: It's not about viewing the page on the front-end but just about the back-end.

Comment: You need to adapt [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77021/12615).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks brasofilo!

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_pages_to_user_except_admins' );
function hide_pages_to_user_except_admins( $query ) {
if( !is_admin() )
    return $query;
global $pagenow;   
$pages = array('201','38','99'); //page ids
if( 
    'edit.php' == $pagenow 
    && ( get_query_var('post_type') && 'page' == get_query_var('post_type') ) 
)
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $pages );

return $query;
}
```