# How do I print a notice only on certain admin pages?

Tags: plugin-development, actions

I'm writing a plugin which would print a notice, but only on the media page. I found the `admin_notices` and `all_admin_notices` actions, but these are fired on all admin pages. Is there any way to find which admin page is the hook being called on from within the callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a global variable called [$pagenow](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Admin_Globals) for the use within WP Admin:

```
global $pagenow;
if ( $pagenow == 'upload.php' ) :

    function custom_admin_notice() {
        echo '<div class="updated"><p>Updated!</p></div>';
    }
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'custom_admin_notice' );

endif;
```

UPDATE: Simply include the snippet in your themes or plugins `functions.php`

Comment: How can I check if I am on admin page `admin.php?page=theme-prefix-theme-settings`?

Comment: `global $pagenow;
if ( ( 'admin.php' === $pagenow ) && ( 'prefix-theme-settings' === $_GET['page'] ) ) { logic.. }` from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7281/77054).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is using the [**`load-{$page}`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29) hook.

Example:

```
add_action('load-edit.php', 'maybe_edit_notice'); // only on edit.php paged

function maybe_edit_notice() {
  // some example notices based on the get variables
  // the url should be something htt://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?done=1&error=1
  if ( isset($_GET['done']) ) {
    $message = isset($_GET['error']) ? 'There was an error.' : 'Everithing ok.';
    $class = isset($_GET['error']) ? 'error' : 'updated';
    global $my_notice_args;
    $my_notice_args = compact('message', 'class');
    add_action('admin_notices', 'print_my_notice');
  }
}

function print_my_notice() {
  global $my_notice_args;
  if ( ! empty($my_notice_args) ) {
    printf('<div class="%s"><p>%s</p></div>', $my_args_notice['class'], $my_args_notice['message']);
  }
}
```

See ['admin_notices' hook docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) on Codex