# how to know if admin is in edit page or post

Tags: admin, editor

I use this after I checked if the user is admin

```
   if ( isset($_GET['action'])  && $_GET['action'] === 'edit' )
```

is there better way?

Comment: Through my testing today, this seems to be the best way to do this with current WP conditionals, because get_current_screen is documented as failing with a fatal error on some admin screens. See the docs for more info, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen

Comment: `but attempting to call get_current_screen() will result in a fatal error because it is not defined.` — well wrapping it in `if (function_exists('get_current_screen'))` then?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`get_current_screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) to determine this.

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
if ( $screen->parent_base == 'edit' ) {
    echo 'edit screen';
}
```

I don't know if I exactly would say this is always better, it depends on what's needed, but it's probably the way I'd do it. The big benefit with this method is that you get access to more information and ergo can do more and different distinctions. Just take a look at the documentation to understand what I mean.

It should be used in later hooks, [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) says:

> The function returns `null` if called from the `admin_init` hook. It
>   should be OK to use in a later hook such as `current_screen`.

Comment: This would prove true on a listing of Posts and Pages, too, though, right? Such as mywebsite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=draft&post_type=post

Comment: @Nathan True, it does. As said in the answer, what is right for the purpose, depends on the use case. This certainly is not the best way to go for *all* cases, but in some cases it is a good if not even the best one.

Comment: Note: Calling get_current_screen() directly in many cases will cause a fatal error. Be sure to wrap it in a function and call it from an appropriate hook.

Comment: $screen->is_block_editor == 1 worked for me to check the edit page. parent_base appears to be empty.

Answer (score 25):

## Better way:

global variable **$pagenow**

```
global $pagenow;
if (( $pagenow == 'post.php' ) || (get_post_type() == 'post')) {

    // editing a page

}
if ($pagenow == 'profile.php') {

    // editing user profile page

}
```

source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7281/33667

Comment: I found this to work except for `$_GET['post_type']`. However, `get_post_type()` worked for me instead.

Comment: `$_GET['post_type']` is only set on `post-new.php`, when creating a new post, and not on `post.php` which is when the post is being edited. `get_post_type()` will work for post.php because the post already exists adn has a post type, but I'm not sure it'll work on post-new.php. Frank's answer is better as it works for both.

Comment: In the first condition, why is there an OR ( `||` ) rather than an AND ( `&&` )?

Comment: than you for the help. it is best answer for some situation.

Answer (score 7):

- Use 'get_current_screen', just make sure beforehand, it exists.
- As [codex says](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) "This function is defined on most admin pages, but not all."
- This btw also filters out normal (reader-facing) views (re-read that
  sentence, with emphasis on *admin pages*).
- quite likely the next thing you want to figure out is, if you are actually on a page or post...

  ```
  // Remove pointless post meta boxes
  function FRANK_TWEAKS_current_screen() {
      // "This function is defined on most admin pages, but not all."
      if ( function_exists('get_current_screen')) {  

          $pt = get_current_screen()->post_type;
          if ( $pt != 'post' && $pt != 'page') return;

          remove_meta_box( 'authordiv',$pt ,'normal' );        // Author Metabox
          remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv',$pt ,'normal' ); // Comments Status Metabox
          remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv',$pt ,'normal' );      // Comments Metabox
          remove_meta_box( 'postcustom',$pt ,'normal' );       // Custom Fields Metabox
          remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt',$pt ,'normal' );      // Excerpt Metabox
          remove_meta_box( 'revisionsdiv',$pt ,'normal' );     // Revisions Metabox
          remove_meta_box( 'slugdiv',$pt ,'normal' );          // Slug Metabox
          remove_meta_box( 'trackbacksdiv',$pt ,'normal' );    // Trackback Metabox
      }
  }
  add_action( 'current_screen', 'FRANK_TWEAKS_current_screen' );
  ```

Comment: thanks for sharing, get_current_screen() is the right tool to use as it offeres a good amount of data.