# How to check if the current page is the permalink page?

Tags: permalinks

Do any of you know a way to check if the current page is the permalink admin page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you check if you are in a particular page in the WP Admin section? For example how can I check if I am in the Users > Your Profile page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/how-can-you-check-if-you-are-in-a-particular-page-in-the-wp-admin-section-for-e)

Comment: What's the problem this is trying to solve? You may not need to know this and use dedicated actions and filters depending on what you're doing

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// 'current_screen' action fires after the current screen has been set
add_action( 'current_screen', 'my_check_current_screen' );

// $current_screen is WP_Screen object passed by the 'current_screen' action
function my_check_current_screen( $current_screen ) {

    // compare current screen ID to the string of your choice
    if( 'options-permalink' === $current_screen->id ) {
        echo 'I am on the "Permalink Settings" screen';
    }
}
```

You can check what you can play with using the `'current_screen'` action instead of `global $pagenow`:

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'my_print_current_screen_object' );

function my_print_current_screen_object( $current_screen ) {

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $current_screen );
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below lines into your function.

```
global $pagenow;
echo $pagenow; // This should give you current page of admin page
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want to do. But basically, you can use:

`is_page( 'contact' )  // To see if this page is the page contact`

`is_singular( 'post' ) // To see if this is a spefic post type`

`get_permalink() // To get the permalink of a post inside the loop`

`global $pagenow // To get the page you are now`

If you explain better what you want, it is easier to offer a better answer.